# Failed to create Ionic 2 blank project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new in ionic 2 framework. I already install cordova and ionic globally. When I try to create a blank ionic project that a empty folder is create. So how can i resolve from this problem.

[image]

Download not start. Please help me!!!!

Comment: What specific version of ionic are you using? Run: ionic -info

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of any sort?

Comment: What happens if you browse to https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz ?  It should download a file.

Comment: Your request probably timed out. Try running the command again.